# Unable to save JStree state with cookies

Tags: jquery-plugins, jstree, jquery-cookie

I am creating the tree with JStree and trying to save the tree state with a cookie plugin, but I'm unable to do so.

Whenever I refresh the page, the tree is collapsed and starts from the beginning. Do I need to write any special code for preserving the state and refetching from cookie?

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
  drawJsTree();
});
function drawJsTree(){
var totalNodes = 0;
$("#jstree").jstree({
        "themes" : {
            "theme" : "classic",
            "dots" : false,
            "icons" : true
        },
        "cookies" : { 
                    "cookie_options" : {
                                    "path": "C:"

                                    } 
                }, 
        "types" : {
            "types" : {
                "root" : {
                    "icon" : { 
                        "image" : "http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0rc/_docs/_drive.png" 
                    }
                },
                "leaves" : {
                    "icon" : { 
                        "image" : "http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0rc/_docs/_drive.png" 
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "json_data": {
            "data": (function(obj){
                var s = this.get_settings().json_data
                var newNodes = [];  
                for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    totalNodes += 1;
                    newNodes.push({"data" : "Node " +(totalNodes-1), "attr": {"id": "node" + (i + totalNodes) , "rel" : "root"}, "state": "closed"});
                }
                if (obj!= -1)
                {
                                    // get parent / grandparent node
                    var lists = $(obj).parents('ul');
                    var p = $(lists[0]).prev('a');
                    var gp = $(lists[1]).prev('a');
                    var t= {
                        "parent": $.trim(p.text()),
                        "grandparent": $.trim(gp.text()),
                        "id": obj.attr ? obj.attr("id"): 1,

                    };
                }
                var d = this._parse_json(newNodes, obj);
                if(!d) {
                if(obj === -1 || !obj) {
                    if(s.correct_state) { this.get_container().children("ul").empty(); }
                }
                else {
                    obj.children("a.jstree-loading").removeClass("jstree-loading");
                    obj.removeData("jstree_is_loading");
                    if(s.correct_state) { this.correct_state(obj); }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if((obj === -1) || !obj) { 
                        this.get_container().children("ul").empty().append(d.children()); 
                    }
                    else { 
                        obj.append(d).children("a.jstree-loading").removeClass("jstree-loading"); obj.removeData("jstree_is_loading"); 
                    }
                    //this.clean_node(obj);
                }       
                if((obj) && (obj!= -1))
                    obj.removeClass("jstree-closed").addClass("jstree-open").children("a").removeClass("jstree-loading");               

            })
        },
         "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "types", "cookies"]
    })
    .bind("select_node.jstree", function (NODE, REF_NODE) {
            /*var newNodes = [];  
                for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    newNodes.push({"data" : "Node " +i, "attr": {"id": "node" +i, "rel" : "root"}, "state": "closed"});
                }*/
                $.jstree._focused()._get_settings().json_data.data = [];
                $.jstree._focused().refresh(-1); 

                $.jstree._reference("#jstree").destroy();
                self.drawJsTree();
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in jsTree cookies plugin. Plugin initialization code should unescape data read from jquery cookie plugin. To fix this, find and change following line

```
tmp = $.cookie(s.save_opened);
```

to

```
tmp = unescape($.cookie(s.save_opened));
```